#   "SQL Injection" issue preventing correct form submission - PHP

Tags: php, forms

So I've been checking everything I can think of to make sure my input fields are all safe from any type of SQL Injection. The good news is they are safe. The bad news is there is one tag that messed up the form submission in a place that it shouldn't even touch and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

This is the exact html used(It's in a template file so forgive the `{$variables}`:

```
<div width="100%">
{$content}

{if $show_form != false}
    <table class='Tfs_forum TFS_body ui-corner-all'>
    <thead><tr><th class="TFS_header ui-corner-all">{$table_header}</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td class="TFS_userinfo loginlink ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        BBCode enabled. HTML will be parsed.<br><center>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[p]','[/p]')">Paragraph</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[b]','[/b]')"><b>Bold</b></button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[i]','[/i]')"><i>Italic</i></button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[u]','[/u]')"><u>Underline</u></button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[s]','[/s]')"><s>Strikethrough</s></button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[size=20px]','[/size]')">Font Size</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[color=red]','[/color]')">Font Color</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[center]','[/center]')">Center Text</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[url=]','[/url]')">Link</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[img]','[/img]')">Image</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[list]','[/list]')">List</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addtoreply('[*]','')">List item</button>
    </center></td></tr>
    <form method="post" action="{$submit_url}">
    <tr><td>
        <input type="hidden" name="forum" value="{$forum_id}"><div style="margin-left:10%;"><label>Topic title: <input type="text" name="new_post_title" value="{$title}"></label></div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <label><div style="margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%;">Content:<textarea id="replybox" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;" name="new_post_content">{$formcontent}</textarea></label></div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <div style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><button type="submit" name="new_post_submit"><span class="save"></span>Submit</button></div>
    </td></tr></tbody>
    </form></table>
{/if}       

</div>
```

Okay this is the entire php script that gets executed until it sees that there is no data posted(None of the forum fields are being posted):

```
<?php
class TForumSystem_NewPost extends PHPDS_controller
{

public function execute()
{
    include("BBCode.class.php");
    include("includes.class.php");
    $this->template->addCSSToHead( Allincludes::css() );
    $this->template->addJsToHead( Allincludes::js() );



    //Main variables here
    $db_category = "***";
    $db_forums = "****";
    $db_posts = "****";
    $db_replies= "****";
    // $db_posts, $db_category, $db_forums, $db_replies;
    //$forum_view_url = $this->navigation->buildURL('forum-view');
    $view = $this->factory('views');
    $maincontent = "";
    $forum_link = ($this->navigation->buildURL('main-forum'));
if(!isset($_POST['forum'])) {
 $this->template->info("Invalid forum, please navigate to the main <a href=\"$forum_link\">forum</a>");
 $view->set('content', "Invalid forum, please navigate to the main <a href=\"$forum_link\">forum</a>"); $view->show();
}
```

The problem is when I use something such as `' or 1='1` or `' or 1=1--` in the title field, none of the data gets posted, I am currently using print_r($_POST) to see what is being submitted, and nothing is.

It works flawlessly for any other statements though, and I should also mention that this script works flawlessly on my local machine, but when using my host I come across the problem stated above.

This is a list of all the inputs I tested that mess it up:

```
' or 1='1
' or 1=1--
'" or 1=1--
' or 0=0 --
' or 'a'='a
```

Comment: the actual code would be more helpful rather than description of what it does. But, please, make sure you post just a part of it - the essence which you think causing the issue

Comment: I have edited your post for code formatting and easy readability. Your HTML didn't make alot of sense though, so I changed it to look logical. If what I made of it isn't right, feel free to change it again though.

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST)` to see everything in the post. Will help with debugging. If it doesn't help, at least post what it says here.

Comment: @TazmanianTad Are you sure `forum` is not setting after form submit. Because i have tried your code and it is working fine.

Comment: Okay guys, I tried print_r on $_POST, it didn't have anything in it.. this is the entire php code from the top of the script to where it checks if forum is set:

EDIT: Nevermind, posting in original

Comment: Keep in mind this code all works flawlessly except with a few "SQL injection's" such as `' or 1='1` and `' or 1=1--` also messes it up, however things such as `' '` and `' or '` work just fine..

Comment: @TazmanianTad Are you using the `action` on the form to post directly to that PHP page or are you using some kind of javascript AJAX with validation?

Comment: Using the action to post directly. If any of you are interested in trying this on the live site I will get you a link, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well I sort of figured it out. Before I was create the forum inside a php variable and then outputting it to the template, instead I put the form directly into the template and it seems to have worked, thanks for all the help!

Edit: Nevermind, we have new evidence. It works fine on my local machine, however it's still not working on my host.. I am sooo lost here..

Comment: The only possible conclusion I can come up with is it has something to do with the htaccess rewrite rules, but the problem is it works for everything except a few of these little sql snippets